# How to recover deleted commit files after git checkout HEAD~2

Tags: linux, git, github

after doing a git checkout HEAD~2 right after commit, the untracked files that I commited are gone in the local repository, since checkout does return the working dir to previous commit, but how can I recover those files or the "new changes" made to my local working directory  without performing the latest commit. The latest commit wasn't pushed. The other user's commits on the repo became staged since the head was detached to the latest commit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git checkout HEAD~2 (example) deletes untracked files if they were added with last commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699466/git-checkout-head2-example-deletes-untracked-files-if-they-were-added-with-la)

Comment: The difference between the two questions is that the other one has checked out before commit, this one is checked out after commit.

Comment: It's the same situation and the accepted answer should be able to solve your problem. If you forget the new commit, run `git reflog` to find it out. If you want the files to be untracked instead of being staged, run `git reset` after `git checkout $newcommit -- file1 file2`.